# Rails md5 hash, gibbon, and mailchimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gibbon

I am using the gibbon gem to connect to MailChimp. I am trying to retrieve a user from my list using their email address. According to: https://github.com/amro/gibbon the way to do this is the following:

```
gibbon.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).retrieve
```

I can get everything to work e.g. adding a new user

```
   gibbon.lists(list_id).members
      .create(body: {email_address: "#{email}", status: 'subscribed'} )
```

This works fine, but if I try to retrieve one record I get an error: `Gibbon::MailChimpError: bad URI`

I am 95% sure it's because I am not submitting the email as a `lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address`

Right now I am submitting the request as follows:

```
gibbon.lists(list_id).members({email: email})
  .update(body: {status: 'unsubscribed'} )
```

What exactly is the `lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address` format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please try following code to generate `lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address`

```
require 'digest'
lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address = Digest::MD5.hexdigest('YourMail@example.com'.downcase)
```

for more detail please check [reference link](https://asyoulook.com/computers%20&%20internet/rails-activejob-background-job-keeps-pinging-mailchimp-repeatedly/468611)